# int limit in permutation program (C++)

Tags: c++, permutation, factorial

I wrote a simple C++ program that computes permutations/factorials in 2 different methods. The problem arises when I try to use the longer method (p1) with 20 and 2. Granted, "20!" is a HUGE number. Is there a limit with integers when calculating the factorial using the recursion method?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int p1(int n, int r);
int p2(int n, int r);
int factorial(int x);

int main()
{
    cout << p1(10, 8) << endl;
    cout << p2(10, 8) << endl;
    cout << p1(4, 3) << endl;
    cout << p2(4, 3) << endl;
    cout << p1(20, 2) << endl;    // THE NUMBER PRINTS INCORRECTLY HERE
    cout << p2(20, 2) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int p1(int n, int r)   // long version, recursively calls factorial
{
    return (factorial(n) / factorial(n - r));
}

int factorial(int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (x > 0)
        return (x * factorial(x - 1));
}

int p2(int n, int r)    // shortcut, does arithmetic in for loop
{
    int answer = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < r; i++)
    {
        answer *= n - 1;
        n--;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: yes there's a limit. Use `unsigned long long` to push the limit a little further.

Comment: is that where I do return (factorial(n) / factorial(n -r))? or within the factorial function? Also (since I'm new to this website), is there an easy way to include the line #'s for the code when I post here?

Comment: `int factorial(int x)` should be `unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long x)` if you want to use big numbers. But there will be a limit too. Just higher. And no you cannot include the line numbers for your code, which would be a nice touch.

Comment: `factorial(n)` overflows. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fh3a000.aspx) are some limit for msvc.

Comment: @h4le5torm If you use [boost multiprecision](http://ideone.com/UvdgWa), those issues of overflow become a moot point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`20!` is `2.4*10^18`

You can check out a reference of [limits.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) to see what the limits are.

consider that `2^32` is `4.2*10^9`.  `long int` is usually a 32-bit value.

consider that `2^64` is `1.8*10^19`, so a 64-bit integer will get you through `20!` but no more.  `unsigned long long int` should do it for you then.

```
unsigned long long int p1(int n, int r)
{
    return (factorial(n) / factorial(n - r));
}

unsigned long long int factorial(unsigned long long int x)
{
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (x > 0)
        return (x * factorial(x - 1));
}

unsigned long long int p2(int n, int r)
{
    unsigned long long int answer = n;
    for (int i = 1; i < r; i++)
     {
        answer *= n - 1;
        n--;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

If you are allowed in this assignment, consider using `float` or `double`, unless you need absolute precision, or just need to get to 20 and be done.  If you do need absolute precision and to perform a factorial above 20, you will have to devise a way to store a larger integer in a byte array like @z32a7ul states.

Also you can save an operation by doing `answer *= --n;` to pre-decrement `n` before you use it.

Comment: Yeah I had a friend look at it and they recommended the `--n` part too! This isn't an assignment, just something I decided to do for fun to test permutations that we discussed in our class.

Comment: Awesome!  Hooray coding because you can :D  Well, if you like the answer, then please check it as the answer.  Or any of the others, just don't forget and leave the question open.

Answer (score 0):

20! exceeds the integer range. Your shortcut function doesn't exceed simply because you don't calculate the whole faculty, but 20*19

Comment: That's exactly right. The long version calculates 20*19*18*17*...*2*1. While the shortcut only does the 20*19.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need it, you may create a class that holds a variable-length array of bytes, and define operators on it. In that case, only the available memory and your patiance will limit the size of numbers. I think Scheme (a LISP dialect) does something like that.